# How to generate coredump file in alpine container

Tags: alpine-linux

I'm trying to work on a open source TSDB [TDengine](https://github.com/taosdata/TDengine), and compile it in alpine to make it dockerized. After compiled, just run the `taosd` binary, it causes segment fault(coredumped), but I can't find the core file.

I've searched and use sysctl to set the core pattern and ulimic -c is unlimited. But it failed to apply sysctl like below.

```sh
# ulimic -c
unlimited
# sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=core-%e.%p.%h.%t
sysctl: error setting key 'kernel.core_pattern': Read-only file system
```

How to generate the core file in alpine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

```sh
docker run -it --rm --ulimit core=-1  --privileged -v $PWD:/coredump <myimage> bash
```

In container, set core pattern and run app:

```sh
sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=/coredump/core-%e.%p.%h.%t
app # coredumped to /coredump/ directory
```

Since we mount $PWD to /coredump, so we can see core file in current directory.